# How would I create a button using an input field?

Tags: javascript, user-input

So I'm trying to have the user input a number into the input field, and when they click the submit button, it will create the amount of buttons they put into the input field. For example, they put '4' in the input field, hit the Submit button, and it will create 4 buttons.

I've done the same with paragraphs. Code here:

```
function submit()
{
    if(!isFinished)
    {

        var choice = parseInt(document.getElementById("paragraphs").value);

        if(choice > 0 && choice <= 5)
        {
            var para = document.getElementById("paragraphs").value;
            var container = document.getElementById("container");

            while (container.hasChildNodes()) 
            {
                container.removeChild(container.lastChild);
            }
        
            for (i = 0; i < para; i++)
            {                
                container.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Paragraph Number " + (i+1)));
                var input = document.createElement("input");
                input.type = "text";
                container.appendChild(document.createElement("br"));
            }
    
            console.log(para + " paragraphs were created.")
        }
    }
}
```

How would I go about doing the same with buttons?

Comment: If you’ve accomplished “*the same with paragraphs*” why are you having trouble with buttons? Where does your code break, what errors are reported? Where is your “*[mcve]*” code for the button creation? Your html for that code, and the css? There are several variables you’d shown code relies upon that aren’t declared in your code. What are those variables, where are they declared and initialised?

Answer (score 1):

Agree with David, more detail needed in the question. Hopefully the below can help point you in the right direction though! :)

```
function submit(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  
  var choice = document.getElementById("paragraphs").value;
  var container = document.getElementById("container");
  
  // clear container buttons
  container.innerHTML = "";
  
  // add buttons
  for (var i = 0; i < choice; i++) {
    var button = document.createElement('button');
    button.innerHTML = "Button " + i;
    container.appendChild(button);
  }
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/9kufoev1/